# Emulator is vanishing when Android Studio is closed

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I have both Android Studio and VS Code editor installed on Linux Mint and Emulator and all functions work just fine. When I use VS Code editor for Flutter I see the Emulator if it is still running through android studio and the moment I close Android Studio , my emulator disappears
I don't see it on VS Code any more.

I am wondering is there a settings that I need to check so that I can use the emulator that is there from VS Code Editor?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Under tools->emulator, there's a setting that controls whether the emulator runs standalone or inside Android Studio

Comment: Not sure what property are you referring can you please be specific? I am in emulator settings, thanks

Comment: Never mind, I found it and it is all good! Thank you so much!